# How can I restrict service accounts from viewing the backups of other accounts in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, backup, service-accounts

I have created 2 service accounts in my local sql server. each of these service accounts has their own databases however if I login by one of these service accounts then I will be able to see the list of the backup files of the databases of the other account when referring to backup and restore section. How can I restrict that?
I already have modified the file permission of the backup folder but it didn't work.